# Ansible - Junos

Tags: ansible, ppa

I am trying to use ansible with Junos devices, following this doc:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/junos_command_module.html

I have created the this playbook:

```
- name: run a set of commands
  junos_command:
    commands: ['show version', 'show ip route']
```

And this other one:

```
- name: run show version on remote devices
  junos_command:
    commands: show version
```

But I am receiving these errors:

```
ERROR! 'junos_command' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/home/joseluis/junos_command.yml': line 1, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: run a set of commands   ^ here
```

I have the following versions:

- ansible 2.3.0.0-1ppa~trusty
- junos-eznc (2.1.3)
- jxmlease (1.0.1)

What can I do?

Comment: @jasonwryan please don't add the Ubuntu tag just because the OP happens to be using Ubuntu (and you don't know that they are, Ubuntu-based distros can also use PPAs). The tag should only be used if the question is somehow specific to Ubuntu itself.

Comment: @terdon then it should be tagged ppa (if that exists). My point was to indicate that this may not be vanilla ansible; which *is* material to the question.

Comment: @jasonwryan ah. You may well be right then. I don't know enough about ansible to know if it's relevant. Fair enough, feel free to add it back then (I'm on mobile).

Answer (score 1):

The lines you posted are **Tasks**.

In a playbook you should at least specify the target **hosts** and **tasks**.

```
- hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: run show version on remote devices
      junos_command:
        commands: show version
```

See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#basics

Comment: Please accept my answer :)